# Compound class names not permitted for a dropdown web element (Selenium)

Tags: jquery, scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a dropdown who's inspection looks like this:

[image]

I want to check all the `li` elements and see if one of them contains the text "Other" for example...

So im writing in scala and I did this:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown-menu open")).click()
val myDropDown = driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown-menu open")).findElements(By.tagName("li"))
val answer = myDropDown.exists(a => a.getText == "Other")
println(answer.toString())
```

apparently its not true, what do you think I should do?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check for all the li elements then u can try this :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-menu open']")).click();
List<WebElement> liList =
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-menu open']//li[@class='nya-bs-option']"));
for(WebElement wb : liList)
{
   if(wb.getText().contains("Other"))
   {
     //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find by By.cssSelector instead of By.className. By.className doesn't support compound css as you mentioned. So your code should be:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("dropdown-menu open")).click()
val myDropDown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("dropdown-menu open")).findElements(By.tagName("li"))
```